# Missing columns during print out

Tags: c#, sql

I'm getting pretty frustrated. Yes im a newbie, 2 weeks old in C# and sql server. Please go easy on me. This command is supposedly to print out InvDate, InvoiceNo, TaxAmount and SubTotal as Amount. its also supposed to drag Patientdetails from another table called PatientsDetails. The key in both is MedicalRecordID.

```
SqlCommand objCmd = 
  new SqlCommand("SELECT CONVERT(char(80), inv.[InvDate],3) 
                     AS InvDate,inv.[InvoiceNo],inv.[TaxAmount] + inv.[SubTotal] 
                     AS Amount, 
                     '' AS Payment 
                     FROM [Invoice] inv 
                     LEFT JOIN [PatientDetails] tab 
                     ON inv.[MedicalRecordID] = tab.[MedicalRecordID] 
                     WHERE (inv.[InvDate] >= CONVERT(datetime, '" + 
                                                      dtpFrom.Text + "', 105 )) 
                     AND (inv.[InvDate] <= CONVERT(datetime, '" + 
                                                    dtpTo.Text + "', 105))", 
                   objConn);
```

This next set of commands are to print out as i want it to be.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    if (!objReader.IsDBNull(i))
    {
        string s;
        s = objReader.GetDataTypeName(i);
        //MessageBox.Show(s);
        if (objReader.GetDataTypeName(i) == "char")
        {
            sw.Write(objReader.GetString(i));
        }
        else if (objReader.GetDataTypeName(i) == "money")
        {
            sw.Write(objReader.GetSqlMoney(i).ToString());
        }
        else if (objReader.GetDataTypeName(i) == "nvarchar")
        {
            sw.Write(objReader.GetString(i));
        }
    }

    if (i < 3)
    {
        sw.Write("\t");
    }
}

count = count + 1;
sw.WriteLine();
```

This is my SQL query which i guess is apparently wrong, because im not adding a SubTotal, but this is actually what i want. The InvoiceNo, InvDate, SubTotal tagged to the user.

```
SELECT Invoice.InvDate, 
        Invoice.InvoiceNo, 
        Invoice.TaxAmount + Invoice.SubTotal, 
        PatientDetails.GivenName 
FROM Invoice 
INNER JOIN PatientDetails 
ON (Invoice.MedicalRecordID = PatientDetails.MedicalRecordID)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following to write out the result

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    if (!objReader.IsDBNull(i))
        sw.Write(objReader.GetValue(i).ToString());
    else
        sw.Write("NULL");

    if (i < 3) 
        sw.Write("\t");
}

count += 1;
sw.WriteLine();
```

If you're still missing fields, I would write your query as follows

```
SqlCommand cmd = objConn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT inv.[InvDate]
                          ,inv.[InvoiceNo]
                          ,inv.[TaxAmount] + inv.[SubTotal] AS Amount
                          ,tab.GivenName
                      FROM [Invoice] inv 
                           LEFT JOIN [PatientDetails] tab 
                                  ON inv.[MedicalRecordID] = tab.[MedicalRecordID] 
                     WHERE inv.[InvDate] BETWEEN @From AND @To";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@From", fromDate);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@To", toDate);
```

You can also use `WHERE inv.[InvDate] >= @From AND inv.[InvDate] <= @To` instead of `BETWEEN`